# MongoDB: How to group by one field, find the max field in the group and output the entire record

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a user's location added into a document every few seconds, and I need to query and return a list of users' most recent location and time.

A document sample record is as follows. (Of course there are lots of such records.)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c99185292e2243299768611"), 
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5c898f5f92e224329827027f"), 
    "time" : ISODate("2019-03-25T18:05:06.000+0000"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -122.98866207168987, 
            49.213194044878996
        ]
    }
}
```

The following code always returns "TypeError: db.getCollection(...).aggregate(...).result is undefined":

```
db.getCollection("user_location").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "user_id" : "$user_id"
                }, 
                "time" : {
                    "$max" : "$time"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "user_id" : "$_id.user_id", 
                "time" : "$MAX(time)", 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
).result.forEach(function(match) {
    // Find matching documents per group and push onto results array
    results.push(db.user_location.findOne(match));
});
```

The expected behavior is to output all the fields in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I first sort the entire collection, then group by user id and push each document into 'docs', since the collection was sorted these are still in order. I then replace the document per player with the first document in the 'docs' field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": { "time": -1 }
  },
  { 
    "$group" : {
      "_id" :"$user_id",
      "docs" : {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
       "newRoot": {
         "$arrayElemAt": ["$docs",0]
       } 
    }
  }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : true
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just to clarify that there are different values for user_id, and the same user_id can have many records with different location and time; the requirement is to get the user_id, time and location info for the most recent location info. 

the first script only returned one record; 

the 2nd script returned following error:

Unable to execute the selected commands

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 16945 (Location16945): 'Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.'

Comment: I misread your question, I've updated my answer. As for iterating over the output I don't think you need 'result' there since the type is a cursor anyway. Just call forEach directly on it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The new code works, but very slow. For 140k records, it took 0.5 seconds, it's weird that after adding index for time field with descending order, it even increased the time to 0.5 seconds. Is there anyway to make it faster?

Comment: I can't think of another way at this time. It's only going to get wore as your collection grows though since mongo has to keep a full copy of the collection in memory to be able to execute this operation. If you add more RAM, it'll be faster since it won't need to use the disk as much, but it's still going to cause problems in the long run. Hopefully, someone else sees the question and sees a solution I'm missing.